# jQuery UI - Unable to style several DatePicker elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI `DatePicker` widget and customizing by my own style. Since this is not really an open source I'm having troubles styling the title of the date picker:
1. Currently the title shows the full month name with a capital letter, how do I make it all capital?
2. It uses two `png` arrows to draw the `next` and `previous` signs. I just want to replace it with `<` and `>` as a plain text, not another `png` element.
3. It seems `next` and `previous` are stand-alone elements, unrelated to the month name and year, this means whenever I resize the window these elements remain static while the calendar always stays in the middle of the page. How do I align them on the right and left sides of the month and year text?
EDIT
4. How can I transform the year to show only the last two digits? from 2015 --> 15.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmk3f010/)

CSS:

```
/* picker width and position*/
.ui-datepicker{
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*eliminate the underline of a tags*/
.ui-datepicker a{
    text-decoration: none;
}


.ui-datepicker table {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse; /*remove double border*/
}

/*header*/

.ui-datepicker-title {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    left: -335px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/*the arrows definition*/
.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url('../img/arrow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*the arrows position*/
.ui-datepicker-prev {
    position:relative;
    left: 50px;

}
.ui-datepicker-next {
    position: relative;
     left: 350px;
}

/*days names treatment*/

.ui-datepicker th {
    padding: 5px 0;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #666666;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
}


/*unselectable*/
.ui-datepicker-unselectable .ui-state-default {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: lightgrey;    

}

/*hover*/
.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-hover {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
//            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            inline: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            dayNamesMin: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednsday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

EDIT2
This is what the title should look like (only with different arrows):
[image]

Comment: do you load the jquery  css? (cause i dont see it on fiddle (or you don't want to load it?))

Comment: No, its my own style.

Answer (score 2):

To make the Title Uppercase, add

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

to `.ui-datepicker-title` in your `CSS`.

To change the png images,

remove

```
background-image: url('../img/arrow.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

from `.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next` in your `CSS`

To set the `<` and `>` as previous and next text, use `nextText` and `prevText` as config options.

And for the last question, i think you have some problem with the CSS. Check it once more, as such a problem never happens with the default one.

To show the last two digits only, in your config please add

```
dateFormat: "dd-mm-y"
```

eg:

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-y"
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'm afraid your solution for the year format is not working, it has not effect. Regarding the `<`, it did work, however the text is small, how can I make it larger and "wrap" the date? Eventually to make it look like `< MAY 15> ` ?

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09ow582o/)

The changes  in code:

```
.ui-icon, .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w, .ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next {
    background-image: none !important;
}
.ui-datepicker-prev:after {
    content: '\003c';
}
.ui-datepicker-next:after {
    content: '\003e';
}
```

As for your last request, i'm not sure what you mean as the calendar renders on the entire page.

Comment: usage of `!important` is not at all appreciated. Instead of using `!important` we should try finding out the exact root of the problem and solve it.

Comment: I agree, it's best practice to find out the origin of that, but, since jQuery is a huge library I just default to that.

Comment: if we know the class names, what is the difficulty in doing find and replace?

Comment: Sometimes people don't have access to the original CSS file... especially if they import it from CDN.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you..just pointed out that, it is not a best practice to use `!important`.

Comment: Lol, it kind of seems like you did, anyhow, I hope my reply is putting your mind at ease. :)

Comment: oh never..i wasnt..you mistook..any way happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. `.ui-datepicker-title { text-transform: uppercase; }`
2. Set `nextText` and `prevText`. See: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-nextText
3. I'm not sure what you mean here. They should already be on the left and right sides and should respond to resizing the calendar. Post a specific example that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rmk3f010/3/

As already mentioned:

For uppercase title:

```
.ui-datepicker-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

For textual arrows:

```
nextText: '>',
prevText: '<',
```

And finally for the alignment:

```
.ui-datepicker-prev {
    float: left;

}
.ui-datepicker-next {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to "wrap" the month and year with those `<` and `>` and not floating them to the edges?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with wrap? You can make them absolute with an with of 50% so that they overlap the complete title ...

Comment: To make it look like: `< MAY 2015 >`

Comment: Don't think that there is a elegant solution for <May 2015> because the datepicker lacks of afterSomething events ...